# Angular2 - Custom directives inside form misbehavior

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-forms, angular2-components

I'm having trouble with custom directives with `<input ...>` tags in it's template, when they are inside an angular form.

If you declare an input inside a form, editing the input's field will alter form's properties, like pristine, touched, valid, etc, as expected.

If you declare a custom directive inside a form, say `<ac2-string-input ...></ac2-string-input>` and it's template includes an input, then if you edit this input's field, it **WILL NOT** alter the form's property.

Why is that? Is that a bug? Is there any workaround for this?

Below you have an example:

We can have a form component, in **app/form.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'

import { InputComponent } from './input.component'

@Component({
    selector: 'ac2-form',
    templateUrl: '<build path>/templates/form/form.html',
    directives: [InputComponent]
})

export class FormComponent {


    item: Object = {
       attr1: 'blah',
       attr2: 'another blah'
    }

    constructor(){}

    submit(){ console.log(this.item) }
}
```

with a template **templates/form/form.html**

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <input type="text" name="attr1" [(ngModel)]="item.attr1"/>
  <ac2-string-input [obj]="item"></ac2-string-input>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<div>
    Pristine? {{f.form.pristine}}
</div>
```

And *ac2-string-input* directive is defined in **app/form/input.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector: 'ac2-string-input',
    templateUrl: '<build path>/templates/form/input.html'
})

export class InputComponent {
    @Input() obj: Object;

    constructor(){}
}
```

with a template **templates/form/input.html**

```
<input type="text" name="attr2" [(ngModel)]="obj.attr2"/>
```

If we load the form, there will be two text fields, and the form will be "Pristine"

[image: Form]

If we edit the "attr2" field, the form will continue to be pristine, as if the field was not bound to the form!

[image: field edited, form pristine]

If we edit the "attr1" field, the form will not be pristine, as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11360) in Angular 2's github.

Turns out that if we want our component to be recognized as a form control, we need to implement `ControlValueAccessor` interface and put ngModel at the top level.

[THIS](http://plnkr.co/edit/NXurYlUBnStK90SXAJUe?p=preview) Plunkr shows how to do this.

Credits go to [kara](https://github.com/kara) who solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The inner `input` is probably not recognized as being part of the form, since `ac2-string-input` is not a standard HTML input.

You can verify this by outputting the forms' controls or value and looking for the `attr2` property.  If it's not there, `Angular` doesn't even know about it, so changing that input has no impact on the form's `pristine` state.

To make integration easier, consider using an attribute directive instead of a component.  This would change:

```
<ac2-string-input [obj]="item"></ac2-string-input>
```

To

```
<input type="text" [ac2StringInput]="item"/>
```

And the Directive would be something like:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[ac2StringInput]',
    host: {
        // onKeyup gets executed whenever the input receives input
        '(keyup)':'onKeyup($event)'
    }
})
export class InputComponent {
    constructor() {}

    /**
     * ac2StringInput to the outside refers to obj within this directive
     */
    @Input('ac2StringInput') obj:Object;

    /**Handle keyup*/
    onKeyup($event){}
}
```

You could even pass the whole `form` as an input into the directive if you want more visibility into what's going on outside of it.

Comment: I really need to insert html, just like what happens when we use "Component". Is there a way to do it with "Directive"? For example, if I use an attribute directive in a `<div ...></div>` to produce`<div ...><input ...></div>` and work with the form?